$A \in M_{n}(\mathbb{Z})$, $A^2 = A-I_{n}$ Is it possible?
I'm searching a $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that I can find a matrix $A \in M_{n}(Z)$ verifying my relation.
n is necessary even and for n=2, it is impossible:
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{pmatrix}
where (a,b,c,d) $\in$ $Z^4$
, because $tr(A)=1=a+d$ and $b(a+d)=b-1$ with my relation
I think that is impossible for $n>2$,
but How can I justify it with case n=2?

This would mean $\lambda^2-\lambda+1$ is the minimal polynomial for $A.$ The relationship would be $a+d=1, ad-bc=1.$ So the equation would be to find $a,b,c$ such that $a(1-a)-1=bc,$ which can happen in lots of ways. We can always choose $b=a^2-a+1,c=-1, d=1-a.$ When $a=1,$ this gives $b=1,c=-1,d=0.$

How do you obtain $b(a+d)=b-1$?

The question for higher dimensions is that it is only possible for $n$ even. This is because the two eigenvalues must come in equal numbers.

See this duplicate for $n=3$.

Thanks (for "b(a+d)=b-1",I made a deadly error of calulus which brang me here...)

Notice that the requirement $A^2 - A + I_n = 0$ means that $A$ is a root of the polynomial $X^2 - X + 1$. There is a nice method of constructing matrices which are the root of a given polynomial via companion matrices. This means that
$$A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$
is an example of a matrix with $A^2 - A + I_2 = 0$.
Edit: I'll follow the recommendation of Greg Martin posted in the comments.
Above, I gave an example of a $(2 \times 2)$-matrix $A$ satisfying $A^2 - A + I_2 = 0$. Out of this, we can produce examples of $B \in \mathrm{Mat}(2m \times 2m, \mathbb Z)$ satisfying $B^2 - B + I_{2m} = 0$: we may simply take
$$B = \mathrm{diag}(\underbrace{A, \ldots, A}_{m \text{ times}}).$$
Now, we can of course ask whether there are matrices $C \in \mathrm{Mat}(n \times n, \mathbb Z)$ for $n$ odd satisfying $C^2 - C + I_n = 0$. In fact, this cannot happen. This is because the relation $C^2 - C + I_n = 0$ means that the minimal polynomial of $C$ divides the polynomial $X^2 - X + 1$, hence has no real roots. However, since $n$ is odd, $C$ has a real eigenvalue, so the minimal polynomial of $C$ must have a real eigenvalue, too.
Observe that this argument even shows that there is no $C \in \mathrm{Mat}(n \times n, \mathbb R)$ satisfying $C^2 - C + I_n = 0$ for odd $n$.

I recommend making the answer more complete by adding: (1) one can form examples for any even $n\ge2$ by making a block diagonal matrix with $\frac n2$ copies of $A$; (2) there are no examples (even with real entries) with $n$ odd since the roots of the required minimal polynomial $t^2-t+1$ come in complex conjugate pairs.

@GregMartin Done, thanks for the suggestion. :)

Thanks, that's what I thought. It is known that if it is true for n=2, it is often true for n even (by making diagonliazed Matrix of 2x2). Nethertheless, if it is not true for n=2, You can't use such a trick (problem of logic).
